# How to include custom attributes in spaCy's Doc.from_docs function?

Tags: python, customization, spacy-3

There is a method `Doc.from_docs()` in spaCy3 (here are links to [the code](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/spacy/tokens/doc.pyx) and [the high-level documentation](https://spacy.io/api/doc#from_docs)) which would come in handy for a project I'm working on. This method concatenates a list of Doc objects into a single Doc object.

On a high level, here's what the method does:

1. convert all input Doc objects to numpy arrays via `Doc.to_array()`
2. concatenate the resulting arrays
3. create single Doc object from the numpy array resulting in step (2) via `Doc.from_array()`

I would like to find out how to make this `from_docs` method take into account also custom attributes. Currently, native spaCy attributes like e.g. "POS" or "DEP" are considered and any related tags are transferred from the original input Doc objects to the resulting concatenated Doc object. However, any custom attribute extensions (i.e. `Doc._.*`) are lost when executing this method.

Does anyone know how to include custom attributes in the `Doc.from_docs()` method?

Thank you for any hints.

Answer (score 1):

`Doc.from_docs` only includes `Token` and `Span` extensions.

(What value should the final merged doc include for `doc1._.ext = True` + `doc2._.ext = False`?)

Comment: Thank you for this point which if course is valid. Let's assume I can come up with a meaningful way to patch the `Doc.from_docs` code such that it is still well-behaved in the case you mention. How would I even do it? I guess the question slightly changes then to: "How to include custom extension attributes in the `Doc.to_array` and the `Doc.from_array` methods?"

Comment: Do it outside `Doc.from_docs` as `merged_doc._.ext = merge_my_ext_values(docs)`. Custom extension attributes are not going to be included in `Doc.from_array`.